# Selenium: Extracting only Text with out any sub elements from <p>

Tags: selenium-rc

Below is the sample code

```
<p>
I want this Text
<sup> not this </sup>
.(Need this too).
<sup> and not this </sup>
</p>
```

Using Selenium RC, selenium.getText("//...") bring us the all the text including which are in < sup >.

Is there any way to get the text from `<p>` without `<sup>` tags ?

Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to get the text of the three elements and manipulate the parts you don't want away.  That, or resort to using `getEval()` to run some JavaScript that get's the `<P>` element's `innerHTML` property, then remove the parts inside the `<SUP>` elements yourself.